# Second fundamental form of Kerr timeslice in BL-coordinates

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, kerr-metric

I want to compute the coefficients of the second fundamental form $K$ of a timeslice $\lbrace t=0\rbrace$ in the Kerr metric in Boyer-Lindquist coordinates. I tried to do this via the definition of the second fundamental form, $K(X,Y)=\,^4g(\nabla_X \nu, Y)$ (where $\nu$ is the unit normal of the timeslice), and also via the Einstein constraint equations for vacuum. However, both computations are extremely long and tangled, so I was wondering if someone has already done it, i.e. if I can look it up somewhere, or if there is an easier way.

Thanks!

Comment: What are Einstein constraint eqs?  You mean the field eqs?

Comment: In these days,  all these calculations are made with CAS software packages,  for example Mathematica or Maple

Comment: @magma The Einstein constraint equations are on an initial data set instead of a whole spacetime, so they contain the local momentum- and energy density and the 3-dimensional scalar curvature instead of the whole stress-energy tensor and the scalar curvature of the whole spacetime as in the Einstein field equations (see for example https://sites.lafayette.edu/corvinoj/files/2014/07/ESI-ECE-beamer.pdf.) They are obtained from the Einstein field equations via the Gauss- and Codazzi equations.